# Why is LaTeX giving all of my theorems the same number?

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm

Whenever I try to number my theorems according to the section they are in, they all end up having the same number. I tried the other numbering schemes to see what they do, and the only one that gives different numbers is when I point back to the theorem before it.

Here is my code for all three numbering schemes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\section{numbered by section}
\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{fst}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{fst}\end{fst}
\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{snd}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{snd}\end{snd}

\section{counted}
\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{athm}{Theorem}
\begin{athm}\end{athm}
\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{bthm}{Theorem}
\begin{bthm}\end{bthm}

\section{numbered by name of first theorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{thma}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{thma}\end{thma}
\theoremstyle{plain}\newtheorem{thmb}[thma]{Theorem}
\begin{thmb}\end{thmb}

\end{document}
```

This is what that gives me:

[image]

As you can see, in the first two sections, the theorems did not count properly. What should I be doing differently? While the last version works, I would really like to be able to use the other two. Everything I look up says this is how to do it, so I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: `\newtheorem` declares a new type of theorem environment, not a new instance of that type. Something like `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{lma}[thm]{Lemma}` declares two types of theorem environments, not two theorems.

Comment: @TH. Thank you so much!  That is exactly what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, you found the solution already. If you want different theorem environments to share a counter, use the third numbering scheme. However, why do you define a new theoremstyle for each of your theorems? It suffices to define one for each kind of "theorem-like" environment and use it throughout. For example,

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
The first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The second theorem.
\end{theorem}
```

If you want to use the same counter for definitions and theorems, use `\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}` instead.

Comment: The things I read made me think that I had to give each theorem its own theoremstyle and it's own name.  I did not realize that I was actually defining a new environment each time. Your example clears that up for me.  I've tried a few examples, and I'm now getting the results I was looking for.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bobbinhood -- where exactly did you read about how to number theorems? if you were confused by the (ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf)[amsthm user's guide], something is seriously wrong and we need to correct it.  (i'm the person responsible for maintaining that documentation, and i really don't like to hear that people find it confusing.)

Comment: @barbara beeton I never saw the document you just linked.  I wish I had.  It is much more straightforward than the things I looked at.

I primarily used http://ctan.mackichan.com/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf
I also looked at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems
I used one other pdf, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @bobbinhood -- well, now that you know about the `amsthm` user's guide, you can use it if you have another question. the manual `lshort.pdf` is good, but its coverage of math isn't what it's really aimed at.  regarding the wikibooks page you cite, the `amsthm` user's guide **is** linked there, at the very bottom. well, we at ams can only be responsible for the documentation we distribute; we try to keep that in good order, so if anyone finds a problem, do let us know -- write to `tech-support@ams.org`